# Why and when to use "end-of-period"?

Tags: writing-style, learning

I came across some manuals that refer to **end-of-period.** I wonder as to when and why they would use this style? Please support your answers with examples.

Comment: Please provide examples of the usage that is confusing you.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are referring to when hyphens are used to form *compound adjectives*, such as ***end-of-year*** report.

One [**online website (ODO)**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen) describes it like this:

> With compound adjectives formed from the adverb well and a participle (e.g. well-known), or from a phrase (e.g. up-to-date), you should use a hyphen when the compound comes before the noun:
>
> - *well-known brands of coffee*
> - *an up-to-date account*
>
> but not when the compound comes after the noun:
>
> - *His music was also well known in England*.
> - *Their figures are up to date*.

If you enter `+hyphen +"compound adjectives"` into your favorite search engine, you'll likely find more enlightening examples.